# Error - strong name signature could not be verified. When running application

Tags: c#, .net, strongname

I am working on a .net application (using Visual Studio 2015) and it works fine on primary desktop but, when I try to run the same code-base on another machine I am getting *strong name signature could not be verified. was the assembly build delay-signed* error. Assembly is not deployed in GAC in either of the machines.It is a signed assembly and we have marked it Delay sign-only, the same setting is there on both the machines.

Any help, suggestions to solve this issue will be of great help.

Comment: You have *actually* signed it? You haven't just marked it as delay-signed and then *intended* to sign it?

Comment: Yes, marked it as delay-signed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it working, had to exclude the checking of assemblies, using 
sn.exe -vr on visual studio command prompt.